# Практический вопрос в изучении азов http

Tags: css, http

Подключите стили с именем thr, которые лежат в папке main. Папка находится на уровень выше, чем файл (к которому подключаем)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>codebra</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что вы сами сделали для решения этого вопроса ? И HTTP это _протокол_ передачи информации, в частности, представленной в HTML виде. И т.к. это протокол, то ни за какие стили или еще что либо он не отвечает. Вы имели ввиду HTML. Пожалуйста не путайте эти понятия.

Comment: Да рекомендую переименовать вопрос в стиле "подключение css файла из другой папки"

Answer (score 2):

`<link href="../main/thr.css">`, двоеточие означает что нужно переместиться на один уровень выше, main означает что потом необходимо перейти в папку с названием main ну и thr.css говорит что необходимо подключить ваш файл. Советую почитать про формирование абсолютных и относительных ссылок:[например здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki).